# How to add row instantly in Jtable while receiving data from socket in JAVA?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, jtable, real-time

I have tried to create a program that can view real-time data on jtable from the socket. Program run properly and received data from socket and can be printed on the output terminal. But apending (add row) on Jtable is not working. What i have done wrong and what would be the right way to do that?
Here is my code snap,

```
public void run(){

    try {
            DatagramSocket aSocket = new DatagramSocket (6666);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1000];

            while (true) {
                    DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket (buffer, buffer.length);
                    aSocket.receive (request);
                    String message[]  = new String(request.getData(), 0,request.getLength()).split(",");
                    
                    
                    DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1_liveTable.getModel();
                    table.addRow(new Object[]{message[0],message[1],message[2],message[3],message[4]});
                 }   
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: you __must not__ change a component (nor any of its properties) that's showing from any background thread - do some research about concurrency in swing to learn how to update the ui in a safe manner.

Comment: So how can i view the data on jtable after receiving it? what would be the right way? should i code it without a thread?

Comment: repeating: do some research . .there are tons of examples/tutorials explaining _exactly_ what you need to do.

Comment: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Okay, I will do research on that. Anyway thanks a lot.